# How to run system with auth0 on http-server

Tags: angular, auth0, angular-service-worker

I work on a system that has auth0 login.
I want to add service worker and to test it I want to run the system on http-server (angular).
I try to login and get the error: Callback url mismatch.

I tried to whitelist the url but it's still don't work.

Comment: Please provide more explanations about your issue with code, screen shots, etc. so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

This can be a number of things but a couple good points to check are as follows:

- Making sure you are using the correct client ID
- Making sure you are using the full URL when declaring your values in your Application settings within the Dashboard
- Verifying the URL included in the authorize request is included in that application's Callback URL.

I've also included the Angular Single Page App Quickstart documentation for reference: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2

Thanks!